# Como alterar o valor da variável na Factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Dentro da Factory tem uma variável `countF` com valor 1:

Factory

```
app.factory('testFactory', function(){
    var countF = 1;
    return {
        getCount : function () {

            return countF;
        },
        incrementCount:function(){
           countF++;
            return countF;
        }
    }               
});
```

---

Controller

```
function FactoryCtrl($scope, testService, testFactory)
{
    $scope.countFactory = testFactory.getCount;
    $scope.clickF = function () {
        $scope.countF = testFactory.incrementCount();
    };
}
```

É possível alterar o valor da variável `countF` que está fora do `return` na Factory? Por exemplo incrementa-la de acordo com o `return` de `incrementCount`?

Comment: Do controller? Não. Só se você mover o `countF` pra dentro do objeto retornado pela factory.

Comment: Não, só queria poder alterar o valor da variável na Factory. Porque até onde eu sei o compilador passa somente uma vez na Factory e nas Functions toda vez que forem chamadas.

Comment: Mas de onde exatamente? Acho que não entendi a pergunta então.

Comment: Desculpe a falta de clareza. Quero que a `var countF = 1` possa mudar para o mesmo valor que estiver sendo mandado do Controller. Exemplo para `var countF = 2`.

Comment: Por que você não cria uma método `setCount` na factory?

Comment: Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi a pergunta, mas assim como você tem métodos para obter e incrementar essa variável, você pode criar outro para definir o seu valor (um *setter*):

```
app.factory('testFactory', function(){
    var countF = 1;
    return {
        setCount : function (val) {
            countF = val;
        },
        getCount : function () {
            return countF;
        },
        incrementCount:function(){
            countF++;
            return countF;
        }
    }               
});
```

```
function FactoryCtrl($scope, testService, testFactory)
{
    testFactory.setCount(10);  // seta como 10
    $scope.countFactory = testFactory.getCount; // pega o valor 10
    $scope.clickF = function () {
        $scope.countF = testFactory.incrementCount(); // incrementa a partir de 10
    };
}
```

Comment: Realmente funfou. Não tinha pensado nesta possibilidade. Obrigado.